# HomeBrew Mac change Python Path

Tags: macos, homebrew

I am trying to install PyQT and I used PyQT. Is has been installed using home brew. But When I try to import it, python can't. I get the following warning in Home brew. I am new to Mac and can't figure out how to change the python path. Any help would be great.

For non-homebrew python (2.x), you need to amend your PYTHONPATH like so:
  export PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH

Answer (score 16):

You should edit `~/.bash_profile` (create the file if it does not exist) to set the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable:

```
export PYTHONPATH=`brew --prefix`/lib/python2.7/site-packages:$PYTHONPATH
```

Comment: So in my travels I've learned that `PYTHONPATH` may be expected by various ways that python projects want you to install them. On OS X, when you install Python using `brew`, it does not provide you with `PYTHONPATH` (and indeed you'll likely need to micromanage it in your shell's init script). This appears to not be an issue if you can find a way to install whatever python project it is using `pip`.

Comment: Just a reminder that whenever you change your `.bash_profile` you should restart your terminal or run `source ~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: There is a serious flaw with this approach: it breaks Python 3 and making it unusable. That's because by setting PYTHONPATH you force both py2 and py3 to use the same values.

Answer (score 0):

Since you installed PyQt by using Homebrew, you should also use Homebrew Python 2.

To install it, run: `brew install python`

Now, you can import PyQt normally.