# Python3 can't find and import PyQt5

Tags: macos, python-3.x, pyqt5

I installed PyQt5 with brew and it appears to end up the install process properly.

```
$ brew install pyqt5 --with-python3
```

The problem is that I can't get it to import:

```
Python 3.4.3 (v3.4.3:9b73f1c3e601, Feb 23 2015, 02:52:03) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import PyQt5
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

Where do I start looking to find out why its not working? I thought it would add it automatically to Python using the brew commmand that I used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to find the installation path using:

```
brew info pyqt5
```

and then add it to your Python path, you can find the solution for that here:

[Permanently add a directory to PYTHONPATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3402168/permanently-add-a-directory-to-pythonpath)

Also your question is similar to this one

[HomeBrew Mac change Python Path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033096/homebrew-mac-change-python-path)

Comment: Awesome, that did the trick :) Took a bit of research though since the brew path wasn't the one that actually contained `__init__`, that was two directories further down.

Comment: Was about to do that when I realized the second link you posted is much better since it works automatically and went off to try that :)