# Mac python3 can't import "PyQt5"

Tags: python, pyqt5

I just installed PyQt5 below command.

```
brew install pyqt5
```

Successfully, To install is end.

But "from PyQt5.QtCore import *" in Python code cannot import module.

Output message is **ImportError: No module named 'PyQt5'**

So I check it python path in command line. (python3)

[image: Python environment variables]

You can find line, **'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5'**

**'/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5'** include files below.

[image: file list in PyQt5]

What is problem in situation. how can I fix that problem?.

Comment: This question is almost the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30145751/python3-cant-find-and-import-pyqt5.

Answer (score 0):

All the files under your '/usr/local/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PyQt5' are linked to another folder. Please make sure the linked files exist, or add the linked folder to sys.path and try "import PyQt5" again